# Forbidden (403) Post Request in a "Build React App" but work fine with React App running on "http://localhost:3000/" and PostMan

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-react

I am using Django Rest Framework and React. When I run the react app on "localhost:3000", every post request is accepted and worked fine. But After I build the react app with "npm run build". Then, all POST requests are being Forbidden(403) on `"localhost:8000"`. but still, everything is fine on `"localhost:3000"`

Comment: Likely this is the CSRF token...

Answer (score 0):

Django has [cross-site request forgery (CSRF) protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf). In each form it uses a small extra element that contains a csrf token, and then validates this.

You can extract the csrf token with a JavaScript function [specified in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax):

> ```
> function getCookie(name) {
>     let cookieValue = null;
>     if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
>         const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
>         for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
>             const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
>             // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
>             if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
>                 cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     return cookieValue;
> }
> const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
> ```

then you can make a `fetch` with:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    },
    body: {
        // …
    }
})
```

Comment: It worked for me. But I don't understand why CSRF TokenAuthentication is needed in "localhost:8000" but not required in "localhost:3000". There are no CSRF Cookies in "localhost:3000".

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons:

- Do you have CORS set? I recommend [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers)

```py
# update backend/server/server/settings.py
# ...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    'corsheaders', # add it here
    #...
]

# define which origins are allowed
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
]

# add to middleware
MIDDLEWARE = [
    #...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #...
]
```

- Please check `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py`
- Please try to run Django server with `DEBUG=True` and check more info about the request, you can check it in developer tools in web browser
- Please check at what address your requests are send? I'm using different server address for development and production:

```
import axios from "axios";
if (window.location.origin === "http://localhost:3000") {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
} else {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = window.location.origin;
}
```

- As Willem Van Onsem wrote, it can be the issue with CSRF, but CSRF is enabled by default only for session based authentication (what authentication are you using?)

Please take a look at the following articles:

- [React Token Based Authentication to Django REST API Backend](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/react-token-based-authentication-django/)
- [Docker-Compose for Django and React with Nginx reverse-proxy and Let's encrypt certificate](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/)
- Github Repository with example Django+React project: [Django+React Boilerplate](https://github.com/saasitive/django-react-boilerplate)